# Add product translations throught API (SOAP or REST)

Tags: product, products-management, api, localisation

is it possible to add product translations using the SOAP or REST API?

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the API documentation provided by Magento, [section product updates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html).
There you'll see that the 4th argument in the call is the Storeview ID.

So for translating a product for a single store view AFTER having the product created on the default level please use that call. 
I don't think it's possible to create the product in default level and add translations on other levels at the same time.